# npoi SetCellFormula custom formula in VBA

Tags: c#, vba, excel, npoi

I have an application that fills with data an excel template .Template is .xlsm .In template I created vba function called SumByColor when i try to set a cell formula to this function i get this error :

```
{"Name 'SumByColor' is completely unknown in the current workbook"}
```

I set formula like this :

```
sheet.GetRow(rowIndex).GetCell(startPos + 2).SetCellFormula(string.Format("SumByColor($AQ$7,F{0}:AI{0})",rowIndex+1));
```

Comment: Should you be setting to `"=SumByColor(...)"`?

Comment: no if Iwrite like this "=SumByColor(...)" i get :{NPOI.SS.Formula.FormulaParseException: The specified formula '=SumByColor($AQ$7,F8:AI8)' starts with an equals sign which is not allowed.

Comment: That's weird. When you don't put the equal it seems to think that `SumByColor` is a range name, and when you use the equal it won't let you.
When you say you `have an application`, what type of application are you talking about? And how are you communicating with Excel from your application?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the cell Type as Formula before setting the formula for cell. For Ex:

```
XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(i);
ICell cell = row.CreateCell(1);  
cell.SetCellType(CellType.Formula);
cell.SetCellFormula("SUM(B1:B10)");
```

You can read up more on setting formula and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

How are you assigning the formula? 
Are you trying something like this?

```
Range("A10") = "=SumByColor($AQ$7,F8:AI8)"
```