# NPOI Core - Formula Issue

Tags: c#, npoi

I am trying to create a simple formula of `SUM(E1:E6)` but keep getting a `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream`.  I have put an `=` in front and even made it lower case with no success.  A formula I was able to get to work was `1 + 3 + 8`.  I then tried `E1 + E2 + E3 + E4 + E5 + E6` and that gave the same error.

Here is my code:

```
IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
ISheet sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet("Project Time");

... Other numeric and textual cells fill in and work great

row = sheet1.CreateRow(RowIndex++);

var test = row.CreateCell(ColIndex++);
test.SetCellType(CellType.Formula);
test.SetCellFormula($"1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6"); // WORKS
test.SetCellFormula($"SUM(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6)"); // FAILS
test.SetCellFormula($"SUM(E1:E6)"); // FAILS
test.SetCellFormula($"E1 + E2 + E3"); // FAILS

XSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);

workbook.Write(TheStream);
```

The GitHub location [is here](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI).

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077009/npoi-setcellformula-custom-formula-in-vba.  Remove $  from SetCellFormula($"SUM(E1:E6)");

Comment: @kumarchandraketu the `$` is a prefix for C# string formatting and is not affecting this in any way.  I took it out and got the same result. The documentation link from the SO link you mention also does not show what I am doing and really gave no insights to what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: I'll suggest you to try  SetCellFormula( "=SUM(E1:E6)"); or SetCellFormula( $ "=SUM(E1:E6)"); Sometimes syntax from documentation doesn't work in NPOI so you may have to try your workaround by hit or miss :)

Comment: The `=` will throw an error because it assumes that being that it is a formula.  I posted the answer myself once I got a hold of the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a post to [here](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI/issues/19) I found out that there was an update from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 and that allowed the formula!  Did not check for updates seeing that I downloaded the package yesterday.  But that is on me, it is .Net core and thus is moving quite quickly.